# asp.net GridView textbox filter on change

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that is filtered by a TextBox. It filters when I leave the control. How do I fire the filter when the TextBox changes?

Comment: What you describe is a `TextBox` control with the `AutoPostBack` property set to `True`.  A postback occurs on focus loss, i.e. the `blur` event, typically hitting `Tab` or `Enter`. To fire a postback on every keystroke is not advised.  You could add a bit of javascript that fires a postback after X number of characters typed.

Comment: That's what I need, in addition to firing it off if the value changes and the new value is at least X characters long

Answer (score 0):

I set the `OnChange` event and looked up the value to see if it was at least 3 characters long. If it was I manually called the PostBack:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="_txtEquipment" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onkeyup="checkforEquipmentNumber();"/>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function checkforEquipmentNumber() {
    var txtEquipmentNumber = document.getElementById("_txtEquipment").value;

    if (txtEquipmentNumber.length > 2) {            
        javascript:__doPostBack("_txtEquipment",'');
    }
}
```